# CodeceptJs : element not found with certains characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, gherkin, codeceptjs

I'm using CodeceptsJs 2.0.4 and Gherkin 5.1.0 to test my app.

I have an issue with an xpath expression. When searched text contains " :" or " ?" characters, the CodeceptJs function `waitForElement` doesn't find the element.

For example, I'm looking for element `<a>Some blabla : blablablabla.</a>` :

```
I.waitForElement(".//div[@class = 'myCLass']//a[contains(., 'Some blabla : blablablabla.')]", 60)
I.waitForElement(".//div[@class = 'myCLass']//a[contains(., 'Some blabla ')]", 60)
```

-> Both elements are not found

But with :

```
I.waitForElement(".//div[@class = 'myCLass']//a[contains(., 'Some blabla')]", 60)
I.waitForElement(".//div[@class = 'myCLass']//a[contains(., ': blablablabla.')]", 60)
```

-> Both elements are found

You can test it with `$x(xpath)` function available in browsers

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does browser finds your element? And what exactly you want to achieve, find element which contains some text, or element which has exactly given text?
Have you tried '//a[contains(text(), "Some blabla : blablablabla.")]'?
Try also '//a[contains(text(), "Some blabla : blablablabla.")]'(but firstly first option, I believe it should work)

Comment: hi, yes I tried with `@contains(@text, ${myString})` and it's the same result.